# My page scrolls down too far. Possibly due to position: fixed elements?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scroll, position

Since adding position:fixed elements, my pages have been scrolling too far and the fixed background repeats its self. 
It's not an issue in Firefox, but Chrome shows this issue.
The problem can be seen at:
http://www.25892.rwswebsite.com/listings

It's been driving me crazy for hours. A second set of eyes would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dug around in Web Inspector and was able to fix a few of your problems:

Scrolling too far:

For `<body>`, `overflow` should be `visible`. This is the default value, so it will take this value if don't explicitly set `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` (and nothing else overrides it).

Multiple background images:

Looks like you're setting the background image on both the `<html>` and `<body>` elements. For fixed backgrounds like you're doing here, I like to set backgrounds only on `<html>` (see [here](http://css-tricks.com/just-one-of-those-weird-things-about-css-background-on-body/)).

Also, I you should try using `background-size: cover` for the background image. With `cover`, the image will be sized to the smallest dimension that will allow it to cover both the browser width and height. Browser compatibility is [pretty good](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Thank you!! I'm going to try those solutions!